# Multiple copy values + call macro not working

Tags: excel, vba

I recently started to work with macros and I am trying to copy a selection from a sheet, paste it in the same sheet and to repeat this in the whole workbook.
The problem is that only in the first sheet the values are copied.
I also linked the macros to a button and all macros are in the same module; you can see my sketch below:

```
Sub CopyValues_sheet1()
'
' CopyValues_sheet1 Macro
'

'
    Range("C6:AD47").Select
    Selection.Copy
    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=18
    Range("C53:AD94").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
   End Sub

Sub CopyValues_sheet2()
'
' CopyValues_sheet2 Macro
'

'
    Range("C6:AD47").Select
    Selection.Copy
    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=50
    Range("C53").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Range("C60").Select
End Sub

Sub Button1_Click()

    Call CopyValues_sheet1
    Call CopyValues_sheet2
   
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The way you're doing this, you need to activate the sheet where you wish to complete the copy/paste operation.  Something like this:

```
Sub CopyValues_sheet2()
'
' CopyValues_sheet2 Macro
'
    
    Sheet2.Activate ' <--- Do this!
    Range("C6:AD47").Select
    Selection.Copy
    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=50
    Range("C53").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Range("C60").Select
End Sub
```

If you're doing the exact same thing on every sheet, you might want to parameterize your sub/function with a sheet name, and use something like this:

```
Worksheets("Your_worksheet_name").Activate
```

Comment: Hi Marc. Thank you for answering. I tried and I obtain Error 424 / Object not found. Do I need to define each sheet in another way for it to work?

Comment: You tried what? I just created a brand new workbook, selected a cell in Sheet2, and then ran `Sheets("Sheet1").Activate`, and it switches tabs to Sheet1.  `Sheet1.Activate` works the same. Be explicit about what you tried and where it's failing.